# Dynamically targeting last rows in CSS grid

Tags: css, sass

So, I used the following CSS to dynamically handle the last rows of an unbalanced grid:

```
.agenda-event, .agenda-magazine {
  &:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4),
  &:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ & {
    .agenda-button {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/targeting-first-and-last-rows-in-css-grid-layouts/

This code is based on a 4 grid column. But for some reason, when there are only 4 items left in the grid (so only 1 row). It discards the border-bottom of the FIRST item but leaves the border bottom of the other three (since it's basically the last row, I need the border-bottoms to stay on 0). What am I doing wrong? Is there something I'm overlooking?

[image: border-bottom only empty on the first item]

HTML of the above image:

```
<div class="agenda-group-content">
  <div class="agenda-magazine"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using nth of type, what element are you selecting? Could you post your entire code so that we can see what's happening?

Comment: @adamk22 I don't see what the problem is https://jsfiddle.net/XL2000/4y4kr9z0/1/

Comment: Can we see your HTML? The code in question should work fine as long as there is no other *interference*.

Comment: @Patrick My apologies, I'ved editted the question with an image and the html (simplified). But what I forgot to mention and added to the question, is that that the nth handles two classes. (.agenda-magazine and .agenda-event). I believe that this is where the problem may lie, but I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: @Harry I've added the HTML!

Comment: Very strange. Seems like there could be a Sass/SCSS compiler version issue here. The code works on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWMzWr) but the same one doesn't on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y4kr9z0/2/). The fiddle has the issue that you are pointing out. If I check the compiled CSS selectors in the Fiddle (through Dev Console) and CodePen there are a couple of selectors missing in the chain and they are causing the issue.

Comment: (contd) This selector - `.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button` which is present in CodePen but not in the Fiddle is the reason for your issue. All siblings of `.agenda-magazine` are `.agenda-event` and so without this selector, the sibling's content won't be selected and styled.

Comment: Would I be better off to just use the compiled version of the CodePen in this case?

Comment: @adamk22: I have to leave now and so can't join the chat but yes thats an option. However, the better option would be to update your compiler to the latest version. I checked at http://www.sassmeister.com/ (latest version) and it produces the same output as CodePen.

Comment: @Harry I've used the outputted CSS that you got from CodePen and although it's not a beautiful fix, it does work! I can approve your answer if you put it down below!

Comment: Sure, would do @adamk22. I hope you don't mind me mentioning that there is a possible compiler version problem, do you?

Comment: @Harry of course not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

There is possibly a compiler version problem which is causing the trouble here. The code given in the question when compiled using the latest version of the compiler at [**Sassmeister.com**](http://www.sassmeister.com/) or at [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWMzWr) gives the below CSS. This CSS would work perfectly fine even when you have only 4 elements.

```
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) .agenda-button, 
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button, 
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) .agenda-button,
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button, 
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-magazine .agenda-button, 
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-magazine .agenda-button {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

But when I compile the same code in [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4y4kr9z0/2/), I get the below output (taken from Dev Console):

```
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) .agenda-button, 
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button, 
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) .agenda-button, 
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-magazine .agenda-button {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

As you would see there are two selectors which are missing from the group. They are as follows:

```
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button, 
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-magazine .agenda-button,
```

Here the first one is very critical for the below structure because the `.agenda-magazine` items is the first (and the 4th last item) and all items that follow it as `.agenda-event` items. So without this, bottom border of the sibling elements which are `.agenda-event` won't be nullified.

```
<div class="agenda-group-content">
  <div class="agenda-magazine"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
  <div class="agenda-event"></div>
</div>
```

---

The following selector will not address the siblings in our case because the first item is not `.agenda-event`

```
.agenda-event:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-event .agenda-button
```

and neither would the below one because the sibling elements are not `.agenda-magazine`.

```
.agenda-magazine:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ .agenda-magazine .agenda-button
```

---

**Solution:**

The most ideal solution would be to upgrade the compiler to the latest version but if that is not possible for whatever reason then it makes more sense to just plug-in the compiled version from **Sassmeister** or **CodePen** into the CSS file.

Or alternately, you could avoid manual grouping of selectors and use `@extend` directive. This method seems to work fine even in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y4kr9z0/3/) and so I assume it wouldn't produce any problems even if there is a version mismatch.

```
.agenda-event {
  &:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4),
  &:nth-of-type(4n+1):nth-last-of-type(-n+4) ~ & {
    .agenda-button {
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
.agenda-magazine {
  @extend .agenda-event;
}
```